# Sublime Text 3 Java Interactive Console?

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime to compile and run Java code inside of the Sublime terminal, but the running application wont receive input, and instead just acts like a notepad when run.

Are there any good solutions or alternative applications for Mac? For example:

[image: Example]

This is the text I used to modify the build:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\""],
    "shell": true,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Comment: did you succeed? Would like to know!